# How to bring up a box (listbox) from a button click

Tags: c#, wpf

I am doing this project that needs to list all SQL local and remote servers. Because to find remote servers takes time so I am listing the local servers in the dropdown combobox so users can select an instance from there, which is most of the cases. I have no problem for this part. However, I need to list all remote servers also so I think a smart way to do it is to through a browse button right next to the combo box, so users can click on it if they want to select a remote SQL instance. I can find all remote SQL instances without problems and put them in a ObservableCollection variable. Now the problem is that how I can bring up the listbox, which has all remote server names in it? I assume there are two parts of code that I need: one for xaml and one is the C# code behind for the click event. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I figured out how to bring the contextmenu from a button:

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to bring the contextmenu from a button:

Here is the xaml:

```
                        <Button.ContextMenu>

                            <ContextMenu Name="BrowseButtonContext"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding RemoteSqlServers}"
                                         MouseDown="Select_Click">

                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Button.ContextMenu>
                    </Button>
```

Here is the code:

```
 private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu cm = BrowseButtonContext as System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu;
        cm.PlacementTarget = sender as System.Windows.Controls.Button;
        cm.IsOpen = true;            
    }
```